# JavaScript to animate a smily face by given images

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, function, setinterval

i'm a begginer with JavaScript, i have a question is like changing images every 2 seconds i used array for 12 images and for loop but it didnt work the way i wanted, the changing goes from image 1 to image 12 directly without moving through the whole 12.

this the my script

```
var images = new Array(11) , x=0;
images[0] = new Array();
images [0].src = "images/smile_01.gif";
images[1] = new Array();
images [1].src = "images/smile_02.gif";
images[2] = new Array();
images [2].src = "images/smile_03.gif";
images[3] = new Array();
images [3].src = "images/smile_04.gif";
images[4] = new Array();
images [4].src = "images/smile_05.gif";
images[5] = new Array();
images [5].src = "images/smile_06.gif";
images[6] = new Array();
images [6].src = "images/smile_07.gif";
images[7] = new Array();
images [7].src = "images/smile_08.gif";
images[8] = new Array();
images [8].src = "images/smile_09.gif";
images[9] = new Array();
images [9].src = "images/smile_10.gif";
images[10] = new Array();
images [10].src = "images/smile_11.gif";
images[11] = new Array();
images [11].src = "images/smile_12.gif";
function changeimage(){

setInterval( function ima(){ 
    for ( x = 0 ; x <= images.length ; x++ ){

        document.getElementById("imag").src= images[x].src;
    }

},1000);


}

HTML:
</head>
<body>
<img id = "imag" src="images/smile_00.gif" onload = "changeimage()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The construction of the multidimensional array is unnecessary. You could just do this `images[#] = uri` where `#` is the index and `uri` is the path to your image. Then retrieve with `images[#]` in your interval function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entire loop happens inside `setTinterval`, however for animation become vsible, you need to place each iteration of the loop in `setInterval`,

also as pointed out in comments your array can be simplified;

```
var images = [
  "images/smile_01.gif",
  "images/smile_02.gif",
  "images/smile_03.gif",
  "images/smile_04.gif",
  ...
];

var i = 0,
    image = document.getElementById("imag");
setInterval( function () { 
  if (i >= images.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
  image.src = images[i];
  i++;
},1000);
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, all the code were useful,

Comment: @FarahAlQ, great I could help, please accept as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is to create an array of all source URLs like this:

```
var images = [
    "images/smile_01.gif",
    "images/smile_02.gif",
    ....
];
```

You could use a loop to do this:

```
var images = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    images.push("images/smile_" + i + ".gif");
}
```

Then get the image element from the DOM

```
var imag = document.getElementById("imag");
```

And then run a function which calls itself every 2 seconds, changes the image, and increases a counter

```
function changeImage(i) {
   imag.src = images[i % images.length];
   setTimeout(function() {
       changeImage(i+1)
   }, 2000);        
};
changeImage(0);
```

Bonus: This begins at the first image again after the last has been shown

Also note that unless you preload the images, you will probably get white flashes at least the first time each image is shown.

Comment: Nifty, this could run forever, and always corrects itself using modulo!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var images = new Array(11), x=0;
images[0] = "images/smile_01.gif";
images[1] = "images/smile_02.gif";
images[2] = "images/smile_03.gif";
images[3] = "images/smile_04.gif";
images[4] = "images/smile_05.gif";
images[5] = "images/smile_06.gif";
images[6] = "images/smile_07.gif";
images[7] = "images/smile_08.gif";
images[8] = "images/smile_09.gif";
images[9] = "images/smile_10.gif";
images[10] = "images/smile_11.gif";
images[11] = "images/smile_12.gif";

function changeimage(){

setInterval( function(){ 
  document.getElementById("imag").src = images[x];
  document.getElementById("imag").title = images[x];
  x++;
  if (x >= images.length)
  {
     x=0;
  }
},1000);
  }
```

```html
<img id="imag" src="http://www.terrafloraonline.com/images/userfiles/images/flower01LOW.png" onload="changeimage()" title="start" />
```

You don't need the loop. `setInterval itself is a loop.` Every time interval is run (each second) it adds 1 to `x`. I've corrected your array. If you run this script you can hover your mouse over the image. You will see that the title of the image changes every second. In my example the first image is just a placeholder to make the onload work. If you're going to use this, only copy the code.